# $AB=A^2+A+I_n$ for real square matrices then $AB=BA$

Tags: matrices, alternative-proof

I know how to prove from $AB=A^2+A+I_n$ (with $A,B\in \mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$) that $AB=BA$ by showing that A is invertible. I would like to know if one can derive $AB=BA$ without using that $A$ is invertible.

Comment: Can you show that $A^2 \times A = A \times A^2$?

Comment: I suppose that if the invertibility of $A$ isn't allowed neither is using that $nullity(A)=0$, right?

Comment: $$\begin{aligned}
AB\left(I-A\right)& =(I+A+A^{2})(I-A)  \\
AB-ABA& =I-A^{3}  \\
AB+A^{3}-ABA& =I  \\
AB+A\left(A-B\right)A& =I  \\
A(B+(A-B)A)&=I   \\
\end{aligned}$$ it implies that $|A|\neq0$

Comment: Let $X=A$ and $Y=B-A-I$. You are essentially asking how to prove that [$XY=I\implies YX=I$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3852/if-ab-i-then-ba-i) without taking matrix inverse.

Comment: @CalvinLin Since the matrix product is associativ, yes. But how does this help?

Comment: @Zhiwei Does $|A|\neq 0$ means $\det(A)\neq 0$? If so, you're using the invertibility of A...

Comment: @user1551 My question is : on this particular exemple, with this particular identity, is there another way?

Comment: @Deif Indeed, I'm looking for a another type of proof.

Comment: @user37238 Yes, but I mean its a conclusion of $AB=A^2+A+I_n$,Because you take the determinant for both sides of $A(B+(A-B)A)=I$, you get that $\det(A)\neq 0$.

Comment: @user37238 I don’t understand your response. To prove [$XY=I\implies YX=I$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3852/if-ab-i-then-ba-i) for square matrices $X$ and $Y$, there is no need to take matrix inverse. (In fact, the whole point of proving this assertion is to justify the existence of matrix inverse.) See the answers in the linked question.